# About using singular & plural version of a word in meta description

Tags: seo, meta-description

Here is an example (for page description )

> Prayer To obtain goals. Blessing to open divine channels to ensure you attain your objectives. Pray this to acquire your objective and goal.

Trying to rank for "goals" & "objectives" but thinking by using singular & plural version of a word you might do better in search results? The page/post will only be about 400 words. Key word density for "goals" & "objectives" being between 2% to 3%.

Would this impact the ranking in a negative way?

Answer (score 2):

Meta description doesn't contribute much for ranking. You most definitely want to be tinkering your title and on-page headings as well as text.

Note, however, that all this will unlikely measurably change your rankings. Competing for high-volume keywords is tough. And in most cases, it brings more political value than practical.

Finally, your description is more about religion than goals or objectives. That's definitely how Google will categorize it and only in that religious context would it consider ranking the site for goals or objectives. Words lik

Comment: thank you.
and yes it is for religious context.
its a prayer to help one achieve their goals. 

The post is 500 words.
title - Prayer To obtain goals and objectives.
Keyword Density
5 (2%)goals 
4 (2%)prayer 
4 (2%)obtain 
4 (2%)objectives 

Ended up going with this page description

Prayer To obtain goals. Blessing to open divine channels to ensure you attain your objectives. Pray this to accomplish and fulfill your mission.

Comment: yeah, well, SEO is like a rocket. You not only want to decrease its weight as much as possible (internal optimization), but also get a bunch of fuel for it to fly (external). Either is highly essential for good rankings. Do not expect your rocket to fly with no fuel.